# Reusing a constraint while creating a table

Tags: sql, constraints

While creating a table how can I reuse a constraint that has been mentioned for a previous column?

```
create table ticket_details(
  from_stn char(3)
  constraint chk check(from_stn in ('vsh','mas','ndl'))
  constraint nn NOT NULL,
  to_stn char(3)
  constraint nn1 NOT NULL, (instead of crea)
  seat_no number(3)
  constraint PK primary key,
);
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Make it a domain constraint, and let both from_stn and to_stn be based on that domain.

Answer (score 3):

A domain constraint will be enforced on any instance of the domain. Also: upon change, you'll have to change it in only one place. (the syntax might differ slightly between implementations)

```
CREATE DOMAIN THE_STN CHAR(3) constraint THE_STN_check_da_value check(VALUE in ('vsh','mas','ndl'))
        ;

CREATE table ticket_details
        ( seat_no INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        , from_stn THE_STN NOT NULL
        , to_stn THE_STN
        );
INSERT INTO ticket_details(seat_no,from_stn,to_stn) VALUES (1, 'vsh', 'ndl' ); -- succeeds
INSERT INTO ticket_details(seat_no,from_stn,to_stn) VALUES (2, 'vsh', NULL ); -- succeeds
INSERT INTO ticket_details(seat_no,from_stn,to_stn) VALUES (2, 'lol', 'mas' ); -- fails
```

Answer (score 0):

Reusing a constraint for another column is not possible. You have to define it for other column if you want